# Typescript compile error

Tags: dojo, typescript

I downloaded a definition of `dojo` [from github](https://github.com/fleray/esri_web_playground), but on compile I get this exception.

```
tsc.js(3228, 17) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Argument out of range: position.
```

Is this `Typescript` (using 0.9.0.1 atm) falling over on the size of the file? Its almost 800kb.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a file size problem because I use a very similar declaration file without issues, but it is a compiler issue for sure.

That declaration file and my own are both based on output from the [DojoTypeScriptConverter](https://github.com/stopyoukid/DojoToTypescriptConverter).  I wish I could share my own with you but it's for work so I don't have the liberty.  Maybe you'll have more luck going back to the base version there and modifying as necessary.

Another project you should look into is [Dojo-TypeScript](https://github.com/schungx/Dojo-TypeScript).  This supports dojo >= 1.7 while the other only goes up to 1.6.  I haven't used it because there's no declarations for the deprecated features I need, but it looks promising.

Comment: This looks good for just dojo, but ArcGIS have their own version of Dojo, which as you've pointed out is made using that converter. Guess I will have to wait for future releases.

Comment: Try using the latest TypeScript build from the repo before giving up.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/29/trying-the-latest-typescript-build.aspx  Hopefully that will work for ya.  If that still fails submit a bug report here https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic including the files necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and resolved it by renaming my class which have the same name as a module.

```
export Class A{
    ....
}
export module A{
    ....
}
class B extends A{ // here compiler thinks that A is module not class A

}
```